# SQL Server 2017: IID_IColumnsInfo Bulk Insert Error

Tags: bulkinsert, sql-server-2017

I've used the following script in the past without issue, so I'm not sure why it's causing me issues now.

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

My code:

```
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

[screenshot of setup and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32uiN.png)

- File Size: 112 MB
- Rows: 322,190
- Microsoft Server Management Studio v17.4

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
```

or

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a CSV file the row terminator may be a line feed (LF), which `0x0a` in the hexadecimal notation for.  The example below accounts accounts for this type of row terminator.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.YourTable
FROM 'C:\FilePath\DataFile.csv'
WITH (
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDQUOTE  = '"',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',  
    TABLOCK
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the FORMAT= 'CSV' line

your file may not be RFC 4180 compliant.

this has worked for me and this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is not a byte-order mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file, which will cause this to fail with this error.